# Refrescar un contenedor y no toda la página completa Apache Tiles - Struts2

Tags: java, java-ee, tomcat, struts2

Por favor espero que me puedan ayudar con este tema que me tiene preocupado mucho. Resulta que estoy haciendo una pagina web con el framework Struts2 y Apache Tiles 2.1, el tema es que cuando quiero actualizar solo el body , se refresca toda la pagina incluido los menus y el footer. Como podría solucionar este tema, quiero que tenga las mismas caracteristicas de un SPA , no estoy usando angularJS ya que el proyecto esta muy avanzado.
Acá dejo el código de mi web.xml

```
      <context-param>
       <param-name>
          org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.DEFINITIONS_CONFIG
       </param-name>
       <param-value>
          /WEB-INF/tiles.xml
       </param-value>
       </context-param>

<!-- registramos el filtro controlador de struts 2 -->

     <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
             <init-param>
            <param-name>struts.devMode</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>struts.custom.i18n.resources</param-name>
            <param-value>ApplicationResources</param-value>
        </init-param> 
      </filter>

      <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      </filter-mapping>

       <listener>
   <listener-class>
      org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener
   </listener-class>
   </listener>
```

Y esta es la configuracion de mi tiles.xml

```
<definition name="baseLayout" template="/WEB-INF/template/baseLayout.jsp">

        <put-attribute name="title" value="Template" />
         <put-attribute name="sidebarLeft" value="/WEB-INF/template/sidebarLeft.jsp"  /> 
        <put-attribute name="sidebarRight" value="/WEB-INF/template/sidebarRight.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/template/header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="container" value="/WEB-INF/template/body.jsp" />
    </definition>


    <definition name="tilesPerfil" extends="baseLayout">
        <put-attribute name="container" value="templatePerfil" />


    </definition>

    <definition name="timeLine" extends="templatePerfil">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="TimeLime" />
        <put-attribute name="contenidoProfile" value="/WEB-INF/pages/perfil/timeLine.jsp" />
    </definition>
```

De que manera puedo solucionar este problema por favor, solo quiero que se actualice la parte que deseo modificar y no toda la pagina. Algo así como un SPAs.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eso es imposible, los frameworks SPA son del lado del cliente, en general son javascript. En cambio tiles es un framework que resuelve en el servidor y vacia un resultado al cliente.

Si quieres hacer un SPA te equivocaste de tecnologías, necesitas usar `Angular`, `React.js` o `Vue.js` y del lado del server puedes seguir usando `java` pero ya no usaras `struts2` ni `tiles`. `Struts`, `Struts2` y `tiles` ayudan a implementar `MVC` pero resuelven partes en el server. La parte de `V` (vista) y su implementación entra en conflicto con las aplicaciones SPA.

Si usas `Angular`, `React.js` o `Vue.js` y en el server usas `java`, en `java` lo que tendrás implementado son `WebServices` que utilizan mensajes `json` de preferencia.

`Tiles` no implementa SPA, lo que implementa es el patrón `composite view`

Comment: Tienes razon amigo , perdona por responder tarde , ahora estoy usando Angular y me va muy bien , gracias.