# Error al ejecutar: npm run prod

Tags: laravel, nodejs, npm, sass

Estaba practicando un entorno de producción de una aplicación que estoy haciendo en Laravel y al usar el comando npm run prod me da este error en la terminal:

ERROR  Failed to compile with 2 errors                                                                                                                         11:01:53

error  in ./resources/sass/app.scss

Syntax Error: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
SyntaxError

(259:4) Unclosed block

257 |
  258 |   .navbar-toggler-icon {

> 259 |     background-image: escape-svg($navbar-light-toggler-icon-bg);
>         |    ^
>     260 |   }
>     261 |

error  in ./resources/sass/app.scss

Syntax Error: SyntaxError

(259:4) Unclosed block

257 |
  258 |   .navbar-toggler-icon {

> 259 |     background-image: escape-svg($navbar-light-toggler-icon-bg);
>         |    ^
>     260 |   }
>     261 |

@ ./resources/sass/app.scss 2:14-253

2 assets

ERROR in ./resources/sass/app.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/index.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
SyntaxError

(259:4) Unclosed block

257 |
  258 |   .navbar-toggler-icon {

> 259 |     background-image: escape-svg($navbar-light-toggler-icon-bg);
>         |    ^
>     260 |   }
>     261 |

```
at C:\laragon\www\laravel\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:316:20
at C:\laragon\www\laravel\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
at C:\laragon\www\laravel\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
at context.callback (C:\laragon\www\laravel\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
at C:\laragon\www\laravel\node_modules\postcss-loader\src\index.js:207:9
```

@ ./resources/sass/app.scss

ERROR in ./resources/sass/app.scss (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss0!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-4!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-5!./resources/sass/app.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
SyntaxError

(259:4) Unclosed block

257 |
  258 |   .navbar-toggler-icon {

> 259 |     background-image: escape-svg($navbar-light-toggler-icon-bg);
>         |    ^
>     260 |   }
>     261 |

@ ./resources/sass/app.scss 2:14-253
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @ production: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ production script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-02-12T16_01_53_656Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @ prod: `npm run production`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ prod script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-02-12T16_01_53_792Z-debug.log

Estoy usando Laravel 6.0, npm 6.9.0 y node 12.5.0

Comment: Perdona mi ignorancia y arriesgo de equivocarme, pero creo que deberías usar `php artisan "algo"` para `laravel` ya que `npm` que yo sepa es para `nodejs` y no creo que se puedan combinar ya que ambos son del lado del servidor. Si quieres combinar javascript y php creo que deberias usar `angular`, `react` o `vue` para `frontend` y php para `backend` pero en ese caso php solo serian webservice. Tu pregunata es similar a [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/283689/refrescar-un-contenedor-y-no-toda-la-p%c3%a1gina-completa-apache-tiles-struts2/293513#293513).

Comment: Te está marcando un error de sintaxis en `resources/sass/app.scss`, aparentemente tienes un bloque sin cerrar.

Comment: Para nada es ignorancia amigo, aca todo nos sirve de ayuda... Pero te comento que este es el segundo proyecto en modo practica donde uso Laravel junto a npm y nodejs, incluso en el primero use Laravel, npm, nodejs y VuejS

Comment: Hice una búsqueda rápida y encontré que puede ser por la versión de "sass-loader". Que versión tienes instalada?https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/elixir/npm-run-prod-fails-with-bootstrap

Comment: Como dice @porloscerrosΨ puede ser la version de **sass-loader** o también la menera en la que importas todo esto en tu `app.scss` ¿podrías editar tu pregunta y colocar ambas cosas?

Answer (score 0):

Despues de hacer un find en todos los archivos del proyecto, resulta que el error esta aca:

C:\laragon\www\laravel\node_modules\bootstrap\scss_navbar.scss: pero no veo el error en la sintaxis

```
.navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-image: escape-svg($navbar-light-toggler-icon-bg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Me paso lo mismo y en el package.json tenia

```
"sass-loader": "7.*",
```

lo cambie a

```
"sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
```

ejecute el comando "npm update" y después segui con el comando "npm run prod" a mi me funciono